# C++ user defined function returning incorrrect

Tags: c++, return, user-defined-functions

The value of xSum is correct in the user defined function but when it is returned to the main function it is an incorrect value. Why is the value being returned incorrectly to the main function?

```
double arrayMulti(double X[], double Y[],const int size, double xSum, double ySum, double xySum);

int main()
{
    double slope, xSum, yInt,ySum,xySum,xSqrSum;
    const int size = 10;
    double X[size];
    double Y[size];

    arrayPop(X,Y,size);

    arrayMulti(X,Y,size,xSum,ySum,xySum);

    cout<<xSum<<endl;

}

double arrayMulti(double X[], double Y[],const int size, double xSum, double ySum, double xySum)
{
    xSum = 0, ySum = 0, xySum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        xSum = xSum + X[i];
        ySum = ySum + Y[i];
        xySum = xySum + X[i]*Y[i];
    }
    cout<<xSum<<endl;
    return xSum;
}
```

Comment: How do you know they're different? Your program doesn't have any output.

Comment: I just put a cout in both the main function and the user defined function. The user defined gave -.1088 which is correct but the main function gave 6.76672e-319, this happened with and without the return being in the user defined function

Comment: Please, add that code along with the output to the question not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. Have you turned on warnings? Do that and fix all the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning anything to `xSum` in `main()`. Your `arrayMulti` function takes its parameters by value, so it's not going to change the values that are seen in `main()`. It does *return* a value though.

Probably what you want is something like

```cpp
xSum = arrayMulti(X,Y,size,xSum,ySum,xySum);
```